# Converting HTML User Form input into .sql file that is in the same folder Using PHP (Question)

Tags: php, html, sql, computer-science

The reason why I am asking this question is because everyone seems to say to create a database using myphpadmin or mysql which i am having great trouble trying to setup. Is there an easy way to just have a .html file with a form and PHP code that gathers the users input and simply just pastes it into the .sql file table that I have in the same folder? or must I have to setup a database for this to work?

If its possible to do this without setting up a database how can i go about doing this?

Comment: What is a " .sql file table" exactly? You mean a text file which contains some SQL commands? That's not a database so you can't meaningfully save anything into it, at least not in a way which would be considered a proper database where you could then query the saved data easily in different ways, e.g. to retrieve it, update it, add more rows, aggregate it etc. It's unclear what problem(s) you're having with setting up MySQL, but there _are_ simpler file-based database systems such as SQLite available, which can be used for small applications or learning purposes.

Comment: Yeah i meant a text file that has sql commands. Thank you for this i will try out SQLite and see what i can accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are options, you can use SQLITE and keep the file in a folder, no server needed :)

https://www.sqlite.org/

Obviously this is more suitable to small projects, **if you're looking for intensive use or great amount of storage you're going to have to use a database server**.